# Erro: cannot convert float* to float

Tags: c++

Erro encontra-se na linha:

```
quadrados = (desvio_qualquer * desvio_qualquer);
```

Erro: Cannot Convert Float* to Float

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
struct leituras{
  float vetor[1000];
  int n;
}n1;
//int quadrados(leituras n1, int i, float desvio_qualquer, float quadrados);
int main ()
{
    int i;
    float soma, media, desvio, desvio_qualquer, soma_dos_desvios_de_leituras,x,quadrados;
    cout << "Programa para calcular a media das leituras de um experimento e o desvio da media, o programa trabalha com no maximo 1000(mil) leituras.\n";
    cout << "Digite o numero de leituras que seram inseridas no programa, sendo inteiro não negativas e diferente de zero e menores ou igual a 1000,e use pontos e não virgulas para expressar numeros decimais :\n";
    cin >> (n1.n);
    if(n1.n != 0) {
        for( i=0; i<n1.n; i++)  {
            cout << "Digite as leituras:\n ";
            cin >> (n1.vetor[i]);
            }
        for( i=0; i<n1.n; i++)  {
            soma = soma+n1.vetor[i];
}
        media=soma/n1.n;
        for( i=0; i<n1.n; i++)  
        {
            desvio_qualquer = n1.vetor[i] - media;
            //quadrados(n1.n, i, desvio_qualquer, quadrados);
            soma_dos_desvios_de_leituras = soma_dos_desvios_de_leituras + pow(desvio_qualquer,2);
    }
        x=pow(n1.n,-1);
        desvio=sqrt(x*soma_dos_desvios_de_leituras);
        cout << "A media é: " << media << " \n E o desvio é: " << desvio << endl;

}
    else {
        cout << "Digite a leitura:\n ";
        cin >> (n1.vetor[1]);
        cout << "A media é: " << n1.vetor[1] << " E o desvio é 0(zero)" << endl;
}


  return 0;
}

//int quadrados(leituras n1, int i, float desvio_qualquer, float *quadrados) {

//  for( i=0; i<n1.n; i++){
//      quadrados = (desvio_qualquer * desvio_qualquer);
//}
//return 0;
//}                                 Não entendi o erro.
```

Answer (score 4):

Lembre-se que quando você quer alterar o valor de um ponteiro você deve usar *

Sendo assim, a linha fica assim:

```
*quadrados = (desvio_qualquer * desvio_qualquer);
```

No seu caso você estava tentando dar um valor ao ponteiro, que representa um endereço de memória.

Comment: Obrigado, mas ainda não esta funcionando, olha por favor:

Comment: @user3720765, eu testei e o erro nao mais ocorre. Qual o problema que está ocorrendo? De uma olhada no código que está aqui: http://textuploader.com/0bqr e tenta criar um novo projeto colando no main este código

Comment: struct leituras{
  float vetor[1000];  int n;
}n1;
int quadrados(leituras n1, int i, float desvio_qualquer,float *quadrados);
int main ()
{
int i;
float soma, media, desvio, desvio_qualquer, soma_dos_desvios_de_leituras,x,quadrados;
media=soma/n1.n;
for( i=0; i<n1.n; i++) 
{
desvio_qualquer = n1.vetor[i] - media;
quadrados(n1.n, i, desvio_qualquer, quadrados);
soma_dos_desvios_de_leituras = soma_dos_desvios_de_leituras + quadrados;  return 0;
}
int quadrados(leituras n1, int i, float desvio_qualquer, float *quadrados){
for( i=0; i<n1.n; i++){
*quadrados = (desvio_qualquer * desvio_qualquer);

Comment: agora diz que não pode usar a função quadrados

Comment: Neste caso se o seu problema "cannot convert float* to float" foi solucionado favor marcar a resposta como válida e abrir uma nova pergunta para que assim mais pessoas possam te ajudar. Lembre de adicionar o código fonte formatado.